# How to put at the queue jobs of multibranch project?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

How to disable concurrent build inside multibranch project?
With another words, build one branch at a time, putting other to queue.

`options { disableConcurrentBuilds() }` work only for multiple runs of one branch.

"Build Blocker Plugin" can not to be configured for multibranch.

What else i can try?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `lock`. It's not the ideal solution here, but can be used as workaround. See [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35359) ticket for more details.

Comment: thank you. I sow that ticket. Just hope someone new cute solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've created a separate slave-agent on the same machine that only executes jobs from this specific multibranch-pipeline. This new slave agent must have 1 executor and the job should be fired explicitly to this new agent (i.e. MyMultibranchPipeline_Slave). The "regular" slave will take care of any other concurrent builds that aren't in the multibranch-pipeline.